# connecting to a remote postgresql server

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a server with postgresql running on port 5432. However when I try to connect to it remotly I keep getting a timeout error: curl: (7) Failed to connect to url port 5432: Timed out.

My pg_hba.config file:

[image]

my postgresql.conf file has :
listen_addresses = '*'

and my ufw firewall has:

5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Nmap also shows the port state is Filtered.
I did restart postrgresql.
I think that this is a netwerking issue, however I can't seem to fix it even after 4 hours of trying to connect remotly.

Comment: Can you connect using `psql`? Also `curl` is used for connecting to Web based servers(think HTTP and like)[Curl](https://curl.se/). Pretty sure it does not understand Postgres protocol. If you have a Web service in front of the Postgres database that is what you should be pointing at.

Comment: No I have tried connecting using pg4admin however I to keep getting timout error there

Comment: I have tried connecting using psql shell and keep getting: psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "xxx" (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
Yes it is,

Comment: So either there is another firewall in the mix or you are connecting using IPv6 and you need to un-comment the   `::/0` line in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Yea i have tried that, however it keeps blocking, there might indeed be a upper firewall out of my controle blocking it

Comment: Did you reload the `pg_hba.conf` file after making the change? Is the server running in a Cloud provider?

Comment: Yes I do: sudo service postgresql restart every time I change those files

Comment: I always recommend checking that you can telnet to the server's IP address and port.

Comment: You don't need to `restart` a `reload` is sufficient.

Comment: telenet is also connection timed out, yes just in case I do a restart, shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Yeah, I would be suspicious of any Internet facing server that would allow `telnet` to connect. Is the Postgres server in a Cloud provider?

Comment: Yes, it is a server running on a university cloud server, so I think they block the ports, also ssh instead of telnet is timing out